# How can I transfer pictures from my Canon Digital Rebel XTI (400D) to my Mac?

Tags: file-transfer, os-x, canon-400d

I recently bought a used Cannon EOS Digital Rebel XTI 400D. I went on a trip and took some photos that I would like to get onto my mac (A mac mini running 10.6.8). When I plugged the camera into my mac iPhoto started but the computer did not show the camera in iPhoto or in Finder. I looked for drivers to download but could not find any. For the moment I am using a pc to get them off the camera for the moment, and transferring them with a flash drive but I would like to be able to not have to use such a roundabout process.

Comment: Not a direct solution but it is generally best to use the sd card reader built into the mac for that.

Comment: @Unapiedra The EOS Rebel XTi uses Compact Flash, not SD cards.

Comment: And the Mac Mini doesn't have a SD card reader either...

Answer (score 10):

You need to install Canon's *EOS Utility* in order to download the pictures directly from the camera. Canon DSLR cameras do not appear as generic logical drives like some other manufacturers' DSLRs. EOS Utility is included on the disc that came with the camera. Updates are downloadable at [Canon's website](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/support/consumer/eos_slr_camera_systems/eos_digital_slr_cameras/digital_rebel_xti#DriversAndSoftware) (under the software tab, rather than the drivers tab), but normally either a previous version needs to be installed or the disc present in the optical drive for the download to install. It appears the last version of EOS Utility that officially supported the Rebel XTi was version 2.9.0. The last Mac OS this version was officially listed on the Canon support page as compatible with was OS X, but the user manual lists OS X 10.2-10.4. This may or may not work on your OS X 10.6.8 machine.

If you search for EOS utility via the [EOS Rebel XSi page](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/support/consumer/eos_slr_camera_systems/eos_digital_slr_cameras/eos_rebel_xsi#DriversAndSoftware), there is a listing for a version of the *EOS Digital Solution Disk Software 28.2A for Mac OS X (For users who cannot use the bundled CD)*. The included version of *EOS Utility* (ver. 2.13.20) may or may not support the XTi.

Comment: Or, if that is too complicated buy a compact flash card reader.

Comment: To add to this because i dont think i should add a new answer. try installing VM Ware and run a virtual computer what runs windows XP / Linux.  this may be a work around while you try and figure out a solution for the mac os. 

another thing to check if you are willing to get a bit technical with is checking the device list on the mac, open a terminal and type ls /dev/* before the camera is attached and do it again after the camera is attached.

Comment: @thebtm Canon cameras will not show up as a generic logical drive under any OS, neither Windows, Linux, nor Mac. You must use EOS Utility or another application with the proper code that can access the device to download directly from the camera.

Comment: You can use Image Capture, built in to your Mac to get the images off the camera

Comment: @MichaelClark every OS will register a change. whether the change is usable or not by the OS is what makes the difference. i was merely suggesting to watch the OS to see if it registers the change, whether is a "drive" or other device. I work in IT and troubleshoot Servers, Tape Libraries and personal computers, its why i suggested it.

Comment: Data exchange for Canon cameras follows PIMA 15740-2000, with minor differences. But these differences preclude using the camera as a mass storage device without additional code. There are third party products that do the same thing EOS Utility does, but to the best of my knowledge no publicly released version of Windows, Linux, or Mac OS has contained the necessary additional code..

Answer (score 3):

You should not need the EOS Utility to connect your Canon to the Mac.

Three things to check:

1) EDITED PER BELOW: The Canon 350D (Xt) had a setting on the Setup2 menu that chose PC CONNECT vs PRINT/PTP. If the camera is set in PRINT/PTP, it will not connect to the computer correctly. This is not the case with the Canon 400 (XTi).

2) Check your usb cable

3) On the Mac, you need to instruct OSX what to do when the camera is connected. The fact that the camera does not show in Finder suggests either 1 or 2 above is the culprit. However, OSX can act funny when you have don't have Image Capture configured correctly. In Spotlight, (hit apple+space bar) type 'Image Capture', and hit enter when you see the Application  listed. Your camera should be listed if it is connecting properly. Here you can define what default actions you wish to happen when you connect your camera...for example, you can have iPhoto launch and import begin.

4) If you have a VMware or Parallels running, often these will capture the USB port, assigning it to the OS you have running in the VM. The Mac OSX side will behave as if the camera or printer is no connected.

Comment: There is no such PC Connect option for the EOS Rebel XTi. See pages 107 and 156-7 of the user manual:  http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/7/0900000357/01/EOSDRXTi400DIM-EN.pdf

Comment: The EOS Rebel XTi doesn't even have a 'Tools' Menu. The menus are: *Shooting 1, Shooting 2, Playback, Set-up 1, and Set-up 2*. No Canon compact or DSLR I've ever used has a 'Tools' menu.

Comment: Set-up2 is what I was referring to, and I remembered it as 'Tools', as it has a wrench and screwdriver icon. My appologies. Also, it appears that unlike the 350D, the 400D eliminated the 'Communication' option.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when I bought a second hand Canon 10D EOS. Photos would only load on my old Pentium 11 MAC through a card reader, but nothing worked on my new Mac. I then had a brainwave and trawled the net for an SD to cf adapter thinking there must be such a beast.

There was and it works perfectly. The adapter fits straight into my card reader and down loads all pictures perfectly. For some reason the normal CF will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Mac comes with a program called `Image Capture`. Run it, select the device, and Import all. Canon EOS Utility is not necessary.

Comment: You are assuming the "device" will show up and function properly. That's a tall assumption for EOS cameras. Data exchange for Canon cameras follows PIMA 15740-2000, with minor differences. But these differences preclude using the camera as a mass storage device without additional code. There are third party products that do the same thing EOS Utility does, but to the best of my knowledge no publicly released version of Windows, Linux, or Mac OS has contained the necessary additional code.

Answer (score -3):

If you have Photoshop, just use the import from device function.