# 700D Show "Movie Recording has Been Stopped Automatically" after DCIM Cut in Laptop - Memory Card Problem

Tags: canon, canon-700d

**PS : Please read the case carefully before you think to point this question as a duplicate question. Thanks**

Hi community, thank you for your interest reading this.

I have 700D Canon as a body and kit lens

What i experience is quite unique

My 700D "at first buy" can record video up to one minute or more without any problem. Even at it's most HD resolution.

I always backup my DCIM files (including videos and pictures) to my laptop after i use this 700D in one photography event. I don't use copy feature, i use cut feature instead to free up my DSLR memory card.

Then after that "backup" suddenly my 700D cant record more than 17 seconds or so. It is said "Movie Recording has Been Stopped Automatically" after 17 seconds of recording or so.

The light indicator show red light too. I'm sure its not the problem of 700D itself, im sure something is wrong with the memory card.

There is a moment when i can start to record more than 1 minute again but after "backup" suddenly i only can record 17 seconds or so and it is show "memory card is busy".

What should i do ? Buy a new memory card or there is any way to fix this problem ?

Thanks in advance Photography Stack Exchange Community. Pardon my english.

My Memory Card :

Sandisk Extreme 16GB Class 10

Comment: Does this behavior also show with other cards?  Can you format your current card in the camera (important) and still see the same behavior?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen this is my only memory card, i will format my memory card via 700D body and see if there is any change.. ty

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> What should i do ?

Stop using "cut" and start using a utility that properly deletes the image from the card in a way that won't mess up your camera's file system by deleting files that should be left on the card.

Specifically, with [Canon cameras](http://cpn.canon-europe.com/content/education/infobank/storage_and_archiving/file_numbering_and_naming.do) you need at least one subfolder in the DCIM folder labeled with the proper naming convention for storing image files in Canon cameras (e.g. 101Canon, 102Canon, etc.). You must also have an "CanonMSC" folder that contains .CTG files the camera needs there in order to use the card properly.

If you delete all of the subfolders inside the DCIM folder or if you delete the entire DCIM folder itself, it might be what is causing your issue. Reformatting the card using the camera will restore the needed folder structure and contents.

Also be aware that although some newer operating systems will "see" the camera as an attached device when connected to a computer, there are some minor differences in the code Canon uses in their cameras that preclude using a Canon camera as a mass storage device under standard PIMA 15740-2000 protocol. If you're cutting/pasting from the card in the camera connected to the computer via USB that might be where your problem lies. For more info regarding this, please see [this answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/45141/15871) to [How do I get Canon EOS 5D Mark II RAW files using a USB cable and bypassing the EOS utility?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/45133/how-do-i-get-canon-eos-5d-mark-ii-raw-files-using-a-usb-cable-and-bypassing-the/45141#45141)

Comment: I assume "cut" just means "cut and paste" from a file manager GUI, which will be exactly like copy and delete after. I can't imagine this being problematic in itself on any modern operating system.

Comment: Cameras, particularly Canon cameras, often have minor differences in file systems that can cause such problems. Please see the last comment to this answer: http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/42037/15871

Comment: Beyond that, If you cut/paste the entire DCIM folder then the camera might have issues since what it sees as an essential operating system folder/subfolder is no longer available.

Comment: actually i didnt touch DCIM folder, but i cut and paste what is inside it. thanks for your answer. btw i dont know who downvote your comment because i didn't..

Comment: FTR, also not the downvoter. In any case, to test this theory, formatting the card in the camera should be sufficient to fix it.

Comment: @Keshia If you deleted the CanonMSC folder within the DCIM folder that is likely the source of your trouble.

Comment: @MichaelClark Do Canon cameras not recreate these folders when needed? Every other camera I created ever used does.

Comment: Yep, but that is likely what is happening when the video reaches 17 seconds and the camera bogs down while waiting for the "CanonMSC" folder to be written to the card. Unless the card is formatted in the camera first before shooting, the files aren't written until the user starts shooting.

Comment: I'd be almost willing to bet the buffer of that camera can hold 17 seconds of video at the resolution/frame rate the OP is using.

Comment: i use ctrl+a (select all), is it possible that i move CanonMSC inside DCIM too ? btw thank you, you've been answering my question lately. i choose your answer as the best. really appreciate it

Comment: @MichaelClark when i do ctrl+a (select all) and ctrl+x (cut) inside DCIM folder, is it possible that CanonMSC inside DCIM cut too ?

Comment: Yes, because it must be inside the DCIM folder. That's where the camera puts it when it creates it and that's where the camera looks for it when it is writing to the card. If it is not there the camera will stop trying to write to the card until it can create it. It's not just a simple matter of writing a file to the card, either. It first must access the card's file system and base certain parameters within the file on what it finds.